# Is Not JSON Serializable odoo computed one2many error

Tags: json, odoo, computed-field

this is really good explanation about new API.

Also, I have question regarding computed one2many field. Consider this as example

Class parent has computed one2many field to Class child. I want that the one2many field is automatically filled with some random value.

So, I give my fields compute. Also make a method with @api.depends("some_field").

To insert a value to one2many field from the methods, i use childfield += self.env['class_child'].new({'key':value}).

At parent creation, it works fine, the one2many field is updated everytime the depended field is changed. The problem is at parent edit, when I tried to change the depends value, it got error :

TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

I don't understand what wrong with my concept, am I wrong? or do i need to use another method when editing the parent class.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of code:

```
self.env['class_child'].create({
'key': [(0, 0, {'field_name1': 'field Value', 'field_name2': 'field value'})]
```

For a one2many field, a lits of tuples is expected.

Here is the list of tuple that are accepted, with the corresponding semantics:

> (0, 0,  { values }) #link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
>
> (1, ID, { values }) #update the linked record with id = ID (write *values* on it)
>
> (2, ID) #remove and  delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)

**Example:**

```
[(0, 0, {'field_name':field_value_record1, ...}), (0, 0, {'field_name':field_value_record2, ...})]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work, as it giving another probluem. At parent creation, error like : 'KeyError: <openerp.models.NewId object at 0x08FE0B10>' rises.